# Magento2: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::suncare/tabs.phtml' in module: '' block's name 'magento\framework\view\element\template_4' [] []

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento2: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::suncare/tabs.phtml' in module: '' block's name 'magento\framework\view\element\template_4' [] []

facing this error how to resolve this?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is the problem with windows. Windows uses "" as separator, the array "directories" contains entries with "/" as separator, so the check will always fail. So you need to fix this by replacing the separator in core file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

function **isPathInDirectories** replace below code in **isPathInDirectories** function

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Comment: But, I'm working on linux not windows or any windows server

Comment: Okay You do any customization or it's coming from vendor folder?

Comment: Ok I have found, it was generating due to my customization,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

suncare/tabs.phtml was not exist and called somewhere in module layout